# Best way to handle large number of onClick ids?

Tags: java, android

My android application is like a remote control so there is 30 buttons with 30 unique ids set like the following:

```
android:id="@+id/button0"
android:id="@+id/button1"
.
.
.
android:id="@+id/button29"
```

I want to reduce the very large switch statement I would have to make. Is there a way other than using the switch statement below to handle `onClickListener` for each of these buttons?

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button0:
            myFunction(0);
            break;
        case R.id.button1:
            myFunction(1);
            break;
        .
        .
        .
        case R.id.button29:
            myFunction(29);
            break;

    }
}
```

In my ignorance I tried doing the below:

```
String id = Integer.toString(v.getId());
id.replace("button", "");
int buttonNum = Integer.getInteger(id);
myFunction(buttonNum);
```

But now I see that `v.getId();` will not return `button0` for example. Is it possible to get what number the button is (0-29) from the `View` or `id` in `onClick`?

Comment: what is the value you are getting at buttonNum ???

Answer (score 1):

try to use set tag property and  get value of tag(Button number) at particular button id. like

```
String id = Integer.toString(v.getTag());
myFunction(id);

and in XML 
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5sp"
            android:text="AAAAAA"
            android:tag="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
```